# C# MySQL Get values from query and split every value into a string

Tags: c#, mysql

I've searched all through the internet, and there is no way that I have found to do what I'm asking for. Here's my code:

```cs
using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(verbindung))
{

    connection.Open();

    string query = $@"show tables like '%{tbSearch.Text}%'";
                    MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
    using (MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {

            listR.Add(reader.GetString(0));

            btnAccount.Text = listR[0];
            btnAccount2.Text = listR[1];

        }
   }

}
```

What I expect:

1. To get two strings if there is more than one Table available.
2. I add in the values separately using the code below, considering when I tried using an AutoCompleteMenu it was able to separate each string e.g. PrX#0000 and PxL#0000 are not in the same line or value.
3. Display the values on buttons (I can do this part myself, I just gotta know how to separate values from the Query into separate strings.

What I got:

An error at: btnAccount2.Text = listR[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbG5s.png); with the error being:

**System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index'**

I guess that's because of the string not being separated into 2 by itself

I tried pretty much everything and searched all around the internet, and was still not able to find any way to do this.

Here's the data I'm trying to get from the reader:

[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbG5s.png)

Here's what I get when I show the data of `GetString(0)` in a MessageBox.

[The first table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kl3RZ.png)

[The second table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nrw1V.png)

I get 2 MessageBoxes when I do `MessageBox.Show(reader.GetString(0));`

One normally after I type the first letter of the table in the Textbox, the second after I close the first MessageBox.

Comment: This question doesn't appear to be related to using the Visual Studio application, so I've removed that tag. Please ensure you check you're using the correct tags when asking questions.

Comment: So `while (reader.Read())` loops once per row. You add a single item to `listR`, but try to access the second item. Why is this? How can you access the second item of a list that you've only added one item to, not two?

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama The thing is, once I add GetString(1), I get an error because it doesn't exist. Yet, I get  2 table names in GetString(0). That's what I'm trying to say.

Comment: You get two table names in a single row from a single column of the table? What?

Comment: "System.ArgumentException: 'You have specified an invalid column ordinal.'" When I use `listR.Add(reader.GetString(1));`

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama Let me be more specific. There are 2 table names that exist. I am trying to get both of them, but not in ONE string. However, when I try to get them via `reader.GetString(0)`, `reader.GetString(1)`, the `GetString(0)` only works and not `GetString(1)`, yet I get 2 of the table names in `GetString(0)` instead of getting 1 in `GetString(0)`

Comment: Wouldn't there be two rows though, not one?

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama I've edited the post and added the link to an imgur picture so you can see the data I am trying to receive in separate strings.

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama and what do you mean by rows in this situation? please be more specific. I mentioned tables only.

Comment: Well, in SQL all results are as data sets, which have columns and rows. Have you performed the same query in SQL Management Studio and looked at the results?

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama I have not, but how will doing that help? We've already seen what happens using MySQL with C#. I just want to find a way to split the results into separate strings.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the results in MySQL Workbench/whatever UI admin tool you're using? It would really help to know what the result looks like.

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama I have provided screenshots and some more details in the post. Please check them out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will "get two strings if there is more than one Table available." The loop (around `reader.Read()`) will provide a separate string for each row in the dataset, i.e., each table in your database.

You need to move the access of the two strings *outside* the loop. The first time the loop runs, you only have one string, so you can't access both of them yet.

```cs
listR.Clear();

using (MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (reader.Read())
        listR.Add(reader.GetString(0));
}

btnAccount.Text = listR[0];
btnAccount2.Text = listR[1];
```

Note that this code will still crash if there are fewer than two tables, it will ignore any tables past the first two, and it will pick the first two tables in arbitrary order (because there's no `ORDER BY` in your query).